# Find strings with same openings in r

Tags: r, regex, string

Say I have a df with a column that looks like:

Sentence

```
"Jim plays football and Mike plays soccer."

"Jim plays soccer and Mary plays the piano."

"Mike plays football and Mary plays soccer."

"Mary plays volleyball and Jim plays the piano."
```

...

Are there any regex that I can use to return me all the sentences that start with "Jim", all the sentences that start with "Mike", and all the sentences that start with "Mary"?

I don't know how I can achieve this because I assume that you have to know what you're searching for when using regex, but here what I'm search is varying.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `grep("^(Jim|Mike|Mary)", ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `gsub` and `split` like so

> `^(\\w+)` will look for first word in sentence

```
split(sentences, gsub("^(\\w+).*", "\\1", sentences))

# $Jim
# [1] "Jim plays football and Mike plays soccer."  "Jim plays soccer and Mary plays the piano."

# $Mary
# [1] "Mary plays volleyball and Jim plays the piano."

# $Mike
# [1] "Mike plays football and Mary plays soccer."
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It perfectly solves my problem!